# Run time errors while calling a library function

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux

I have ported an application to ARM-LINUX platform which uses shared libraries. The application starts execution and fails to call a method and exits.

Since the application runs fine on x86, I assume the problem is at the target.
Since the application statrts execution I assume all shared libraries are present on the target.

Does anybody have any suggestions how to solve/debug this ?

Comment: Never assume anything. What happens if the libraries are not the right version, for instance? Can't you run the ARM version in a debugger?

Comment: Thank you, I am a beginner I haven't used debuggers in Linux. I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi,  I bypassed error handling in the code and found out that it is a segmentation fault while binding a symbol from one of the shared libraries.